# inserting +- (i.e. \pm) between two numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, symbols

I want to insert the symbol +- (\pm) between x and y in table created in matlab

```
x = (1:1:5)';
y = x*5/100;
table = [x y]
```

So, that the output is

```
1.0000 +/- 0.0500
2.0000 +/- 0.1000
3.0000 +/- 0.1500
4.0000 +/- 0.2000
5.0000 +/- 0.2500
```

If we can also write the minus exactly below plus.

Comment: char(177) will give the \pm symbol, however i'm unsure what format you want the output in

Comment: I shall be printing the output to .txt format

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode characters in MATLAB. The following works:

```matlab
>> fprintf('%f ± %f\n', table.')
1.000000 ± 0.050000
2.000000 ± 0.100000
3.000000 ± 0.150000
4.000000 ± 0.200000
5.000000 ± 0.250000
```

Note that `fprintf` cycles through all the elements of the input matrix in storage order (down the first column first). So it was necessary to transpose the data array (`table.'`) to print it in one command.

This works for printing to file as well on MacOS:

```matlab
f = fopen('mytextfile.txt','wt');
fprintf(f,'%f ± %f\n', table.');
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

With output as a text file use the format spec for fprintf such as

```
FileID=fopen('FileName.txt','w');

fprintf(FileID,['%1.4f ',177,' %1.4f\n'],[x';y'])
```

Comment: However, the symbol \pm given by char(177) is still missing in the output text file.

Comment: Writing in text file failed but I was able to print to screen with this bit of code: sprintf(['%2.4f ' char(177)  ' %1.4f\n'], [x;y])

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(['%0.2f ' char(177) ' %0.2f\n'], [x;y]);
```